# Ignoring lines when combining CSV files using cat or tail?

Tags: linux, csv, cat, tail, cp

I have been using cat to combine a bunch of csv files before using sort to delete the dupes before importing into MySQL. As dirty as working with tons of csv files can be its been smooth sailing until I found that some of my data is not making it into the db.

What I found was that during the combining of the files, in some cases, the column names (first line of csv files) is getting thrown off into additional columns. The result is when I use sort to remove duplicates and spit out a new file it outputs only up until the line where there was an issue with column names being thrown into new unused columns in the csv file.

I'm using cat like the following:

```
  cat *.csv >combined.csv
```

and sort to

```
  sort -u combined.csv -o cleaned.csv
```

I then made my way to tail which is promising:

```
tail -n+2 *.csv >combined.csv
```

However with how I am using tail I am getting the actual file name in a row right before where each csv file that was combined

```
==> first-file.csv <==
red     | 1234
yellow  | 5678 
blue    | 9123
green   | 4567
orange  | 8901
black   | 2345
white   | 6789
==> second-file.csv <==
brown   | 1234
gray    | 5678 
tan     | 9123
burgundy| 4567
```

Instead of:

```
red     | 1234
yellow  | 5678 
blue    | 9123
green   | 4567
orange  | 8901
black   | 2345
white   | 6789
brown   | 1234
gray    | 5678 
tan     | 9123
burgundy| 4567
```

Any help would be most appreciated here. I am going to have to go through all these files again so I need to get it right this time.

Let me know if clarification is needed. I am running on a mac with production on linux and would ideally like to accomplish this with cat, sort, tail or similar.

EDIT:
To recreate the problem with generic data just save the following data in a as csv in two separate files. I named them test-1.csv and test-2.csv.

```
color, votes, trend
"red", "1234", "1,3,3,4"
"yellow", "5678", "2,3,3,4"
"blue", "9123", "2,3,3,4"
"green", "4567", "5,3,3,4"
"orange", "8901", "2,2,3,4"
"black", "2345", "2,1,3,4"
"white", "6789", "2,5,3,4"
"brown", "1234", "2,7,3,4"
"gray", "5678", "8,2,3,4"
"tan", "9123", "9,3,3,4"
"burgundy", "4567", "2,5,1,4"
```

Then just run:

```
tail -q -n +2 *.csv > combined.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, whenever there's more the one input file, `tail` outputs a header with associate file names. To ditch this feature, use `-q`:

```
-q, --quite, --silent
    never output headers giving file names
```

Your command line should go as follows:

```
tail -q -n +2 *.csv > combined.csv
```

Comment: The headers are gone..thanks! I still have a problem though with what looks to be where the merge happens. The text qualifier is " (double quotes) and it appears that this is where when combining the files additional columns are being added and is where using sort fails.

Comment: Can you post a *small* sample of your input data? Anyways, `sort` allows for specifying the column delimiter with `sort -t 'CHAR'`.

Comment: Excuse me on this...it was a user error on my part :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped! :)

Comment: Umm..I hate to say I think the problem is that the when using tail there is no line break added when combining the files. The text qualifier is fine. If I upload to mysql its fine and gets everything. When I use sort (even with sort -t '"') it still breaks when uploading to mysql. Its pretty clear though...the line where it breaks is the only like with double quotes right next to eachother instead of the next row being broken into a new line.  Any ideas? I

Comment: Sorry! I'd have to see at least a small example in which the newline disappears after running `sort`, to kind of have an idea of what is going on. Can you reduce the data to some small, debuggable toy example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93899/discussion-between-lcm-and-rubens).